# how to implement an iteratation in flatMap function

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop, iteration, pyspark

I'm reading a multi-line-record text file into an RDD. The underlying data is like this

```
Time    MHist::852-YF-007   
2016-05-10 00:00:00 0
2016-05-09 23:59:00 0
2016-05-09 23:58:00 0
Time    MHist::852-YF-008   
2016-05-10 00:00:00 0
2016-05-09 23:59:00 0
2016-05-09 23:58:00 0
```

No I want to transform the RDD so that I get a map of key, (timestamp, value). This can be done in several steps. But I would like to extract that info in one call only (but in Python 2.7 not 3).

The RDD is like this:

```
[(0, u''),
 (12,
  u'852-YF-007\t\r\n2016-05-10 00:00:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:59:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:58:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:57:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:56:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:55:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:54:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:53:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:52:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:51:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:50:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:49:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:48:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:47:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:46:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:45:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:44:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:43:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:42:00\t0\n'),
 (473,
  u'852-YF-008\t\r\n2016-05-10 00:00:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:59:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:58:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:57:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:56:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:55:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:54:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:53:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:52:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:51:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:50:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:49:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:48:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:47:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:46:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:45:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:44:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:43:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:42:00\t0')]
```

For each pair the interesting part is the value (the content). Within that value the first item is the key/name and the rest are values with a timestamp. Therefore I'm trying to use this:

```
sheet = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
    'sample.txt',
    'org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',
    conf={'textinputformat.record.delimiter': 'Time\tMHist::'}
)

from operator import itemgetter

def process(pair):
    _, content = pair
    if not content: 
        pass

    lines = content.splitlines();
    #k = lines[0].strip()
    #vs =lines[1:]
    k, vs = itemgetter(0, slice(1, None), lines)
    #k, *vs = [x.strip() for x in content.splitlines()]  # Python 3 syntax

    for v in vs:
        try:
            ds, x = v.split("\t")
            yield k, (dateutil.parser.parse(ds), float(x))  # or int(x)
            return
        except ValueError:
            pass

sheet.flatMap(process).take(5)
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError: 'operator.itemgetter' object is not iterable

The pair that comes into the function has the char-position (which I can ignore) and the content. The content should be split by \r\n and the first item of the line-array is the key while the others are then yield as key-timestamp-value for flatMap.

So, what am I doing wrong in my process-method?

Meanwhile, due to the help of Stackoverflow and all others, I came up with this solution. This one works perfectly fine:

```
# reads a text file in TSV notation having the key-value no as first column but 
# as a randomly occuring line followed by its values. Remark: a variable might occur in several files

#Time    MHist::852-YF-007   
#2016-05-10 00:00:00 0
#2016-05-09 23:59:00 0
#2016-05-09 23:58:00 0
#Time    MHist::852-YF-008   
#2016-05-10 00:00:00 0
#2016-05-09 23:59:00 0
#2016-05-09 23:58:00 0

#imports
from operator import itemgetter
from datetime import datetime

#read the text file with special record-delimiter --> all lines after Time\tMHist:: are the values for that variable
sheet = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
    'sample.txt',
    'org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',
    conf={'textinputformat.record.delimiter': 'Time\tMHist::'}
)

#this avoid using multiple map/flatMap/mapValues/flatMapValues calls by extracting the values at once
def process_and_extract(pair):
    # first part will be the char-position within the file, which we can ignore
    # second is the real content as one string and not yet splitted
    _, content = pair
    if not content: 
        pass

    try:
        # once the content is split into lines:
        # 1. the first line will have the bare variable name since we removed the preceeding 
        # part when opening the file (see delimiter above)
        # 2. the second line until the end will include the values for the current variable

        # Python 2.7 syntax
        #clean = itemgetter(0, slice(1, None))(lines)
        clean = [x.strip() for x in content.splitlines()]
        k, vs = clean[0], clean[1:]    

        # Python 3 syntax
        #k, *vs = [x.strip() for x in content.splitlines()] 
        #for v in vs*:

        for v in vs:
            try:
                # split timestamp and value and convert (cast) them from string to correct data type
                ds, x = v.split("\t")
                yield k, (datetime.strptime(ds, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), float(x))
            except ValueError:
                # might occur if a line format is corrupt
                pass
    except IndexError:
        # might occur if content is empty or iregular
        pass

# read, flatten, extract and reduce the file at once        
sheet.flatMap(process_and_extract) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y) \
    .take(5)
```

A second version is avoiding the for-each-loop and is 20% faster in the end:

```
start_time = time.time()

#read the text file with special record-delimiter --> all lines after Time\tMHist:: are the values for that variable
sheet = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
    'sample.txt',
    'org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',
    conf={'textinputformat.record.delimiter': 'Time\tMHist::'}
)

def extract_blob(pair):
    if not pair:
        pass

    try:
        offset, content = pair
        if not content: 
            pass

        clean = [x.strip() for x in content.splitlines()]
        if not clean or len(clean) < 2:
            pass

        k, vs = clean[0], clean[1:]
        if not k:
            pass

        return k.strip(), vs
    except IndexError:
        # might occur if content is empty or malformed
        pass

def extract_line(pair):
    if not pair:
        pass

    key, line = pair;
    if not key or not line:
        pass

    # split timestamp and value and convert (cast) them from string to correct data type
    content = line.split("\t")
    if not content or len(content) < 2:
        pass

    try:
        ds, x = content
        if not ds or not x:
            pass 

        return (key, datetime.strptime(ds, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), float(x))
    except ValueError:
        # might occur if a line format is corrupt
        pass

def check_empty(x):
    return not (x == None)

#drop keys and filter out non-empty entries
non_empty = sheet.filter(lambda (k, v): v)

#group lines having variable name at first line
grouped_lines = non_empty.map(extract_blob)

#extract variable name and split it from the variable values
flat_lines = grouped_lines.flatMapValues(lambda x: x)

#extract the values from the value
flat_triples = flat_lines.map(extract_line).filter(check_empty)

#convert to dataframe
df = flat_triples.toDF(["Variable", "Time", "Value"])

df.write \
    .partitionBy("Variable") \
    .saveAsTable('Observations', format='parquet', mode='overwrite', path=output_hdfs_filepath)

print("loading and saving done in {} seconds".format(time.time() - start_time));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My object is not iterable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157153/my-object-is-not-iterable)

Comment: No, it's not. It's about the flatMap function and how to pass an own function-callback instead of using lambda. And within that callback, use yield-return.

Comment: *But I get this error: `TypeError: 'operator.itemgetter' object is not iterable`* so how is it not the same?

Comment: Yeah, that error was frustrating. I did know how to use the pair-argument correctly. the updated version works.

Comment: Yeah. I then got IndexOutOfBoundsError until I realized that the first read of the file contains an empty array as content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itemgetter` returns a function which accepts an object and calls `__getitem__` for each argument passed to `itemgetter`. So you have to call it on `lines`:

```
itemgetter(0, slice(1, None))(lines)
```

which will be roughly equivalent to

```
[lines[i] for i in [0, slice(1, None)])
```

where `lines[slice(1, None)]` is basically `lines[1:]`.

It means you have to make sure that `lines` are not empty first otherwise `lines[0]` will fail.

```
if lines:  # bool(empty_sequence) is False
    k, vs = itemgetter(0, slice(1, None))(lines)
    for v in vs:
        ...
```

Putting it all together including doctests:

```
def process(pair):
    r"""
    >>> list(process((0, u'')))
    []
    >>> kvs = list(process((
    ... 12,
    ... u'852-YF-007\t\r\n2016-05-10 00:00:00\t0\r\n2016-05-09 23:59:00\t0')))
    >>> kvs[0] 
    (u'852-YF-007', (datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 10, 0, 0), 0.0))
    >>> kvs[1]
    (u'852-YF-007', (datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 9, 23, 59), 0.0))
    >>> list(process((
    ... 10,
    ... u'852-YF-007\t\r\n2ad-05-10 00')))
    []
    """ 
    _, content = pair
    clean = [x.strip() for x in content.strip().splitlines()]

    if clean:
        k, vs = itemgetter(0, slice(1, None))(clean)
        for v in vs:
            try:
                ds, x = v.split("\t")
                yield k, (datetime.strptime(ds, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), float(x))
            except ValueError:
                pass
```

Comment: Yeah, because it simply didn't work. If with if not content: ... I still got the IndexError. I haven't found any solution. even testing with len(lines) < 2 then pass ... did not help.

Comment: I hate to say that but simple check for boolness works for me and passes doctests :/

Comment: Works fine. But still trying to change it, because the for-loop makes it damn slow.

Comment: I seriously doubt for loop issue is a problem here. You can implement custom format or small parser to avoid `[x.strip() for x in content.strip().splitlines()]` but you cannot avoid sequential loop here. What makes you think it makes it slow? Have you profiled the code?

Comment: I added another solution to my original post. It's avoiding the for-each-loop but only about 20% faster in the end. Good enough for me.

Comment: It doesn't really. It just push it in a different place :)